# multiple if/else statement conundrum

Tags: android, if-statement

Newb question.
So, I'm making sections of text that are clickable and can expand and contract to show more text from a very helpful tutorial but I'm stuck on the last part. There's an if/else statement for a text section that toggles the content from GONE to VISIBLE. But now I'm trying to adjust the code to include more else statements and I can't figure out what the condition should be.

```
    public class AlabamaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         TextView registration_info;
         TextView info2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alabama);

    registration_info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registration_info);
    // hidden until its title is clicked
    registration_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    info2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info2);
    info2.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    public void toggle_contents(View v) {

    if (registration_info.isShown()){
        Fx.slide_up(this, registration_info);
        registration_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if (//?????){
        registration_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fx.slide_down(this, registration_info);
    }

    else if (info2.isShown()){
        Fx.slide_up(this, info2);
        info2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if (//?????){
        info2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fx.slide_down(this, info2);
    }
    ...
```

This is the original if/else statement I'm trying to adjust.

```
    public void toggle_contents(View v) {

    if (registration_info.isShown()){
        Fx.slide_up(this, registration_info);
        registration_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        registration_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fx.slide_down(this, registration_info);
    }
```

I've tried trial and error for the last couple of hours and the results I get online are a bit much for a newb like me.

Also, I've been wondering if I can make this switch/case instead?

Thanks!

EDIT---try not to laugh lol

Fx code

```
        public static void slide_down(Context ctx, View v) {

    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_down);
    if (a != null) {
        a.reset();
        if (v != null) {
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.startAnimation(a);
        }
    }
}

public static void slide_up(Context ctx, View v){

    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_up);
    if(a != null){
        a.reset();
        if(v != null){
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.startAnimation(a);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Slide down

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
    </set>
```

Slide up

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />

   </set>
```

xml:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/Alabama">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/registration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registration"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="toggle_contents"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

    <!--content to hide/show -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/registration_info"
        android:text="info here"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Info2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="toggle_contents"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

    <!--content to hide/show -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/info2"
        android:text="info here"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>
```

Comment: I guess if you have one condition and has many `if-else` with in then Switch would do the job. If you have 2 different condition then `if-else` is a good idea

Comment: From where are you calling `toggle_contents`?

Comment: the main activity. I added the rest

Comment: Looking at the method, I meant are you calling it on a button click or something?

Comment: Ah. Sorry. The textviews all have an onClick attribute calling toggle_contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job, [for now]:

```
public void toggle_contents(View v) {

    // first set
    if (registration_info.isShown()){ 
        Fx.slide_up(this, registration_info);
        registration_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 
    else { 
        registration_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fx.slide_down(this, registration_info);
    } 

    // second set
    if (info2.isShown()){ 
        Fx.slide_up(this, info2);
        info2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 
    else { 
        info2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        Fx.slide_down(this, info2); 
    }
```

**[EDIT]**

Based on your updated post, I believe this should be enough:

```
public void toggle_contents(View v) {

    if (v.isShown()){
        Fx.slide_up(this, v);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fx.slide_down(this, v;
    }
```

**[EDIT2]**

Since, you're attaching click listener to one textview and expanding/collapsing the other, switch-case seems the way to go:

```
public void toggle_contents(View v) {

    View childTV;

    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.registration:
             childTV = findViewById(R.id.registration_info);

        // Can add more cases here
        default:
             childTV = findViewById(R.id.info2_child);
    }

    if (childTV.isShown()){ 
        Fx.slide_up(this, childTV);
        childTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 
    else { 
        childTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fx.slide_down(this, childTV);
    } 

}
```

NOTE: Currently, two of your views have id as `info2` in the xml. I have taken a dummy id above, you should fix it accordingly.

Comment: I had this for a while but when it's run on my phone it doesn't behave correctly. I have a list of clickable textviews that when clicked on should expand to show more text. The problem with this^ is that when you clicked on one they would all expand, instead of just the one that's was clicked.

Comment: @Emily you need to share more of your code then, especially the Fx.slide_down/up

Comment: I like this a lot because it's so concise. But now if I click on a textview it disappears completely haha. The text that is supposed to expand doesn't ever appear either. When I figure out the answer, I'll post it.

Comment: @Emily I think I understand the problem :). Just post your layout xml

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me but Android Studio is giving me a couple errors. In the switch expression it says that it can't resolve method 'getID()' and it's underlining R.id.registration saying it must be a constant expression. According to the internet, that means I'm required to do if/else statements, ugh. I'll just write a different method for each textview. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @Emily hmm...the errors aren't showing in my IDE...in your comment above you mentioned `getID()`...its `getId()`...maybe thats why you're getting the error?

Comment: Oh my. You're right lol. I thought it defaulted that way but I guess I typed it like that. It works!!